Express.js Backend: 'JavaScript Heap Out of Memory' Error - How to find out the actual reason?
I have a microservice that processes orders, built with Express.js, MongoDB, Redis, and RabbitMQ. It's running on an EC2 instance with a 2-core CPU and 8GB RAM.
Initially, I encountered the following error:
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

To mitigate this, I increased the Node.js heap limit to 6GB. However, after running the application for a few days, the same error reappears.
    
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I need help identifying the root cause of this issue. Specifically, I'm looking for advice on which part of my code or which API might be causing the memory leak. What steps should I take to effectively troubleshoot and resolve this problem?

Possible Causes and Solutions for Memory Issues
1. Pushing Large Data into an Array
If you're adding large amounts of data into an array in a loop, it can consume a lot of memory, especially if the objects being pushed are sizable. This can lead to memory exhaustion. Please recheck your code, if you are pushing multiple objects inside an array with a big loop. To mitigate this, consider processing the data in smaller chunks or splitting the loop to handle smaller batches.
2. Storing Large Data in Redis
When storing large amounts of data in Redis, remember that Redis keeps all data in memory, which can lead to memory exhaustion if the data is too large. To avoid this, compress the data before storing it in Redis and set an expiration time to automatically clear the data when it's no longer needed.To compress the data, you can use zlib

I am using separate redis server. I am processing maximum 50 objects in a single api call, after getting datas from mongo.

Could you identify which api is creating the issue? If no, I think you can use any loggers to identify the issue. This is completely unpredictable. And one more thing, please check the code where you are using promise.all(), cause it also consumes a lot memory.
